# javascript - Audio with no play method

Tags: javascript, audio

I would like to create an `Audio Object` using a constructor like this:

```
       var Audio = function(side, name, src, index, duration) {
           this.side = side;
           this.name = name;
           this.src = src;
           this.index = index;
           this.duration = duration;
       };
```

I have added many objects to a `var audios = [];`,

but when I test playback with the first item on the array:

```
      function playTest(){
         var song = audios[0].src;
         song.play();
      }
```

I learn that "audio has no `play method`".

how do I add this `Audio()` method to my custom constructor?

Comment: what is the `src` object... how is the `Audio` object created

Comment: Also you might be overriding the predefined `Audio` constructor(if it is in the global scope)... so think about renaming it